# Where is the Python env file?

Tags: python, conda, environment

I am trying to find where my python env files are stored. The env subdirectories on my machine is empty. Where else can this file be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
conda info
```

And it will display where your environments are stored (among other things=